# Choppy HD video playback with unity/gnome

Tags: unity, gnome, video, vlc

I have been facing a video playback problem with ubuntu for a long time. Everytime I try to play a 720p/1080p video on my laptop, the performance is choppy with frames dropped every second or so. I face this problem when using Unity or Gnome 3. But if I use Gnome fallback, there is no problem. My laptop is Dell Vostro V130 with Intel HD graphics and 4 GB RAM. I use VLC for video playback. I can't remember ever being able to play HD videos on Unity or Gnome 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have solved itself with latest 14.04 trusty release! :)